# column sorting for ag-grid not working

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid and I am dynamically loading data into it. I have enabled column sorting, however it does not work. Nothing happens when I click on the column header. I'm not sure what the issue is. Below is my code:

```
    var colobj = {};
    for(i = 0; i< file.fieldMetadata.length; i++){

   var len = file.fieldMetadata[i].name.length;

   colobj = {'headerName' : file.fieldMetadata[i].name, 'field' : file.fieldMetadata[i].name, sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null']};

vm.columnDefs.push(colobj);

    vm.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(vm.columnDefs);
    vm.gridOptions.api.setRowData(vm.fileContentsCols);
    vm.gridOptions.enableSorting = true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enableSorting won't work here. Only call to api function will work.

You have to set gridOptions.enableSorting = true from the beginning (not after receive the data).

The gridOptions is merely a holder for initialisation. Once the grid is initialise, the api field is available to interact with the grid, all change to parameters won't work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this? in my table, I'm generating data, then I set the columnDefs with a custom cellRenderer, then I setup gridOptions, create a new Grid, then populate the grid with the gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
Any column that uses a custom cellRenderer doesn't sort.

Comment: I've stopped at version 3 of ag-grid with angularjs1. A sample from me might not be up to date. You should ask a new question with enough details. If you use a customCellRenderer you might need to overload the valueGetter. Not that for my part I was handling sorting from the server, so I'm not too familiar with frontend sorting.

Comment: For those struggling with this, I'm using ag-grid-react v21. I had to set sortable: true in the column definition passed to the AgGridReact component, and then call api.setSortModel with the colId. E.g. `<AgGridReact columnDefs={[{colId: 'myColId', sortable: true, ...}, ...]}` and `api.setSortModel([{colId: 'myColId', sort: 'desc'}])`.

Comment: @GalenLong you helped me, but as of v24 the `setSortModel` method is deprecated. The new way is similar: `columnApi.applyColumnState({ state: [{ colId: FieldDescr, sort: 'asc' }] })`. I call this in the `onGridReady` event.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method as your comparator

```
numberComparator(aVal, bVal, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) {

  if (aVal == bVal) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (isInverted == true) {

    if (_.isNil(aVal) || _.isNaN(aVal))
      return -1;

    if (_.isNil(bVal) || _.isNaN(bVal))
      return 1;
  }
  else {

    if (_.isNil(aVal) || _.isNaN(aVal))
      return 1;

    if (_.isNil(bVal) || _.isNaN(bVal))
      return -1;
  }

  return aVal < bVal ? -1 : 1;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here You Use Custom Sorting,

If Your Row Not Bind with Value Then You Use Custom Sorting.

```
         {
            headerName: "Date",
            field: "date",
            //For Custom  Sorting
            comparator: (valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) => {
              valueA = moment(valueA).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
              valueB = moment(valueB).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
              if (valueA == valueB) {
                return 0;
              } else {
                return (valueA > valueB) ? 1 : -1;
              }
            },
            cellStyle: { 'text-align': 'left' },
            minWidth: 250,
        }
```

Comment: you can use create code block with 3 backticks for code

Answer (score 0):

For people wondering why this is happening in Angular :

I was facing same issue , I was setting enableSorting and other booleans dynamically but after setting columnDefs . 
Due to this order of initialization the enableSorting was not working .

I initialized my boolean fields first  before columnDefs and it worked like a charm :

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    /* table setting should be initialed before setting data

{
    "tableHeight": 300,
    "tableClass": "ag-theme-balham",
    "enableSorting": true,
    "animateRows": true,
    "dragDrop": true,
    "enableColResize": true,
    "sortingOrder": ["desc", "asc", null]
  }
```

*/

```
     this.configService.getGeneralTableData().subscribe((x) => {
      this.generalTableSettings = x;
    } );

    this.configService.getTableHeaderColumnSettings().subscribe((x) => {
      this.columnDefs = x;
    });
  }

 <ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"
    id="myGrid"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [class]="generalTableSettings?.tableClass"
    [enableSorting]="generalTableSettings?.enableSorting"
    [animateRows]="generalTableSettings?.animateRows"
    [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]="generalTableSettings?.dragDrop"
    [enableColResize]="generalTableSettings?.enableColResize"
    [sortingOrder]="generalTableSettings?.sortingOrder"

    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom sorting. It will work like that

```
{
  headerName: 'Name',
  field: 'fieldname',
  width: 120,
  comparator: (value1, value2) => {   // check your own requirement 
    return value1 - value2;    
  },
}
```

for more information read docs

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-sorting/